# vscode for m1 MacBook Pro in c++ including library of z3 solver

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I used vim + g++ for c++ before I found vscode for m1 Mac with c++ be valid ,
now I already setting the `.json` , I can print `HelloWorld` and it's also can find the title include,
but now I got a trouble with z3 solver, it's a third library with c++ , I can use it in vim+(g++) but in vscode , I can't find the path of library, I'm already set path in `task.json` args, but it still not work , I'm so confused with it , because I like vscode more than vim.

this is my `task.json`

[image]

`c_cpp_properties.json`

[image]

this's the code of z3 solver example , I already show the path in include `""`

[image]

Comment: try to copy code where possible, instead of screenshots of the code.

Comment: I already show the input , thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, but the whole code is too big that I just copy the header ,
and output is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9P7D.jpg)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
and I already set "-l" "dylib path " in args of task.json , but I didn't see that work in the command ,
this's the command output
cd "/Users/chiyeh/Desktop/train/" && g++ ccc.cpp -o ccc && "/Users/chiyeh/Desktop/train/"ccc